# Visual Studio 2015: Lines in text editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, text-editor

Is there any option to display vertical lines in VS2015 like in Notepad++ in text editor which indicate/wrap specific block (from { till })?

Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, try installing the extension called "**Indent Guides**". It does exactly what you want.

There's also the extension "**Productivity Power Tools**" which provides this, but it comes with more things which you may not want. If you just want the vertical guidelines and nothing more you should go for "Indent Guides".

Answer (score 2):

The **Indent Guides** extension mentioned by Yan is an excellent one. Should be perfect for your needs. I have linked to it below. It is **free** and compatible with **Visual Studio 2015, 2013, 2012**

[Indent Guides - Visual Studio Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30)

Once it's installed, you can activate it like this:

[image: Indent Guides Image]